# Copy paste - custom increment range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel column that looks like this:

```
H
2    =SUM(C2:D32)    // 1st month expenses
3    =SUM(C33:D63)   // 2nd month expenses  
4    =SUM(C64:D94)   // 3rd month expenses
5    =SUM(C95:D125)  // 4th month expenses
...
```

If I copy and paste cell `H5` to `H6`, then I would get:

```
H
...
6    =SUM(C96:D126)  // not what I want
...
```

But instead, I want line 6 to be `=SUM(C126:D156)`. Instead of typing the range manually how can I automate this ?

Comment: Do you have a column (probably `A` or `B` where you have the month information stored? If so, you should use `SUMIF`.

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX() to set the range, put this in H2:

```
=SUM(INDEX(C:C,2+(Row(1:1)-1)*31):INDEX(D:D,32+(Row(1:1)-1)*31))
```

And copy/drag down